# What exactly is Keras loss in history?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, history, loss

Friends,

I am using a callback function to calculate train and test error after each epoch end by calling model.evaluate() . However if I compare my calculated train loss from model.evaluate(x_train, y_train) it is different from the loss saved in history.history['loss']. The calculated test loss from my callback is identical to the history.history['val_loss'].

So I wonder how does Keras calculate the train loss and what exactly is saved in history.history['loss'] ?

I have to calculate the loss after each epoch for different datasets, since I want to evaluate the performance of losses for a sequential training of multiple datasets.

Anybody have an idea why these losses for training data are not identical. Is there a better way to do it?

This is my code:

```
class MyCustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

def __init__(self):
    self.results = {
         'eval_train' : {},
         'eval_test' : {}
    }

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):

        eval_train = self.model.evaluatex_train, y_train, verbose=1)
        eval_test = self.model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
        self.results['eval_train'].append(eval_train)
        self.results]['eval_test'].append(eval_test)



myCallback = MyCustomCallback()

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                                  epochs=10, batch_size=256, verbose=1, 
                                  callbacks=[myCallback]),validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Yes, this has been asked and answered before, it is different because the loss during training is computed as the weights change, while the loss you computed is with the weights fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont really understand the purpose of not calculating the loss with the fixed weights after the sgd upgrade? What does "weights change" mean? Since I just want to monitor the change of the loss for different datasets during training process, is it correct to plot my calculated loss, or do I make a mistake by using the calculated loss with fixed weights?